# Total of float column in linq query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a linq query, that gets data from a table in a DataContext object. One of the columns in this table has a Datatype of float. I would like to get the total of that specific column. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sum = (from row in table
           select row.value).Sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var sum = context.Foos.Sum(foo => foo.Bar);
```

... assuming an entity type named `Foo` with a numerical column named `Bar`.